# What does the 4 symbol on the top-right signify?

Tags: gui-design

I have seen web modal windows to have the 4 symbol on the top-right. Can someone point me to what it represents?

[image: Modal Window]

I guess going back, the modal box being used in Wikipedia for notifying successful edits made me think that the symbol represents something:

[image: Wikipedia Modalbox]

Comment: Do you have more than one example on separate websites? I suspect it's just an arbitrary character that was meant to be rendered as an icon.

Comment: If you can edit your question to include a little bit more context and some examples that would help attract helpful answers.  I have not personally seen that character before, so I'm not clear on where your screenshot is from.  A little more context might give us more to go on.

Comment: Yes it seems like it is just a placeholder icon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in your image, the close button is "a unicode character"

See documentation:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/reveal.php

Note that the character used in the above example is the multiplication symbol (×, &#215, U+00D7).

One problem with relying on text assets for icons is that the user may be able to change the underlying glyphs leading to confusion.

(Edit)

Linked docs are partially down. The following is quoted:

> Reveal modals are easy to build, just make sure they live right above
>   your closing body tag or they won't work properly. Follow the markup
>   below to get started:
>
> ```
> <div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
>   <h2>Awesome. I have it.</h2>
>   <p class="lead">Your couch.  It is mine.</p>
>   <p>Im a cool paragraph that lives inside of an even cooler modal. Wins</p>
>   <a class="close-reveal-modal">&#215;</a>
> </div>
> ```

Comment: I get a 404 with that link.

Comment: was working. added quoted portion, showing the html ent 215

Comment: zurb just released foundation 4 a few hours ago so it appears their old links are broken in many cases